# Скорость выполнения программы

Tags: java, производительность

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно было сдать программу, которая представляет собой 5 классов и интерфейс. Грубо говоря, нужно было создать класс представляющий множество целых чисел и с его помощью создать класс представляющий объединение множеств, пересечение и т.д. причем так, чтобы , например, объединение множеств менялось динамически: если уберем элемент из одного множества (составляющего объединение) то этот элемент уберется из объединения. У нас в универе есть система, которая проверяет программы, но система очень вредная :) После того, как я послала программу в шестой раз, выдало 0 ошибок, но программа работает очень медленно (60 секунд). А я не имею понятия как её можно сделать быстрее, т.к. с моей точки зрения без этого огромного количества циклов там просто не обойтись.

Помогите,пожалуйста...
Скидываю класс, представляющий множество (`OMOSet`) и класс представляющий объединение множеств (`OMOSetUnion`).

```
public class OMOSet implements OMOSetView {
 ArrayList set = new ArrayList();
    public  void add(int element){
        if(!set.contains(element)){
            set.add(element);
        }

    }
    public void remove(int element){
        if(set.contains(element)){
             set.remove((Object)element);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(int element){
        return set.contains(element);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] toArray(){
        int[]pole=new int[set.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<pole.length;i++){            
            pole[i]=(int)set.get(i);
        }
        return pole;
    }
    @Override
    public OMOSetView copy(){
        OMOSet cp=new OMOSet();
        for(int i=0;i<set.size();i++){
            cp.set.add(this.set.get(i));
        }
        return (OMOSetView)cp;
    }
   }

public class OMOSetUnion implements OMOSetView{//implements OMOSetView{
 OMOSetView setA;
 OMOSetView setB;

  OMOSetUnion(OMOSetView setA,OMOSetView setB){

      this.setA=setA;
      this.setB=setB;

  }
  @Override
 public int[] toArray(){
     ArrayList<Integer> union = new ArrayList ();
     for (int i=0;i<setA.toArray().length;i++){
         union.add(setA.toArray()[i]);
     }
     for (int i=0;i<setB.toArray().length;i++){
         if(!setA.contains(setB.toArray()[i])){
             union.add(setB.toArray()[i]);
         };
     }

     int [] array = new int [union.size()];
      for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
          array[i]=union.get(i);
      }
     return array;
     }

 @Override
 public OMOSetView copy(){
      return new OMOSetUnion(this.setA.copy(),this.setB.copy());

 }

 @Override
  public boolean contains(int element){
      if(setA.contains(element)||setB.contains(element)) return true;
      else return false;
       }

 }
```

Comment: Вы ее отлаживать у себя пробовали? Подозреваю, что там мертвое зацикливание.

Comment: зацикливания нет. все тесты проходит

Comment: имею ввиду,тесты всех методов

Comment: 1. Что внутри OMOSetView ? Вы говорите о 5 классах, а представили только 2.

2. Полагаю, что дело не в циклах, т.к. у вас сложность алгоритма c*N, что впринцепе приемлемо. 

3. На каких входных данных проверяется программа?

4. Чем обосновываете использование ArrayList? Имхо логичнее для этой задачи использовать LinkedList или вообще использовать уже готовый LinkedHashSet.

Comment: 1)OMOSetView это интерфейс. Сейчас в новом ыопросе представлю все 5 классов.
2)не может быть дело в том,что их просто слишком много?+большое колличество использования toArray
3)скину тест для проверки программы

Comment: @evgeniya
А по времени в тестах работает без ощутимых задержек?

Почему вместо `setB.toArray()[i]` сразу не сделать `setB.get(i)`?
Почему используется сырой вариант `ArrayList` в `OMOSet`, когда, судя по методам, его можно типизировать как `ArrayList<Integer>` ?

    for (int i=0;i<setB.toArray().length;i++){
    // лучше так
    for (int i=0, size=setB.toArray().length;i<size;i++){

Comment: Потому что setB это объект класса OMOSet,это не ArrayList.

Comment: время в тестах - 1 секунда

Comment: @evgeniya
Стоит высунуть хотя бы геттер. Иначе вы создаете и копируете целый массив из-за одного элемента. И в ArrayList есть родной метод toArray().

Надеюсь, 1 секунда - это на нескольких тысячах элементов? Попробуйте сделать хотя бы такие мелкие оптимизации, время уже резко сократится.

Comment: @evgeniya
У вас в union может лежать два объекта, которые могут быть set или снова union (подмножество). При попытке скастовать union в set будет ошибка. Потому лучше, не акцентируясь на конкретном типе, брать оттуда toArray (он для каждого типа свой и знает что сделать), а затем слепить в один.

Посмотрел ваш вариант. Должен работать. Но есть варианты ускорения, если что =) Например то, что использование промежуточного контейнера (локального хэш-сета) требует упаковки-распаковки int <-> Integer. Но должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, сделайте элементарные оптимизации, например:
Вместо подобного:

```
for (int i=0;i<setB.toArray().length;i++){
    if(!setA.contains(setB.toArray()[i])){
         union.add(setB.toArray()[i]);
    };
}
```

Сделайте так:

```
int[] bArray = setB.toArray();
for (int i=0; i < bArray.length; i++){
    if(!setA.contains(bArray[i])){
         union.add(bArray[i]);
    };
}
```

Иначе на каждый проход цикла будет создаваться от 2 до 3 копий массива, это и память и ресурсы.

Также советую использовать Set, а не массив в OMOSet.
Потом пересечения, объединения делайте стандартными средствами Set-ов.

Оъединение:

```
Set<Type> union = new HashSet<Type>(s1);
union.addAll(s2);
```

Пересечение:

```
Set<Type> intersection = new HashSet<Type>(s1);
intersection.retainAll(s2);
```

Разница:

```
Set<Type> difference = new HashSet<Type>(s1);
difference.removeAll(s2);
```

Может тогда можно будет все эти циклы убрать.

Comment: @Russtam
Вы во всем правы, только реализовывать множества на основе классов множеств было бы глупым заданием =)

Comment: @Free_ze да вы правы, но я тоже учился в институте, и там было полно глупых заданий )

Comment: @Russtam к сожалению,по заданию,надо использовать OMOSet...если бы это был просто сет,проблем бы не было :)

Comment: @evgeniya так используйте OMOSet, но внутри то можно заюзать обычный сет, или так тоже нельзя?

Comment: @evgeniya
@Russtam к тому, что OMOSet можно сделать оберткой над HashSet из стандартной библиотеки, чтобы велосипедов не изобретать.

Comment: я поняла,но тогда надо будет сделать set public

Comment: @evgeniya

Нееее, не обязательно)

    class OMOSet implements OMOSetView
    {
        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

        public void add(int value) { set.add(value); }
        public void remove(int value) { set.remove(value); }

Comment: @Override
        public boolean contains(int element) { return set.contains(element); }
        @Override
        public int[] toArray() { return set.toArray(); }
        @Override
        public OMOSetView copy()
        {
            OMOSet cloned = new OMOSet(OMOSetView);
            cloned.set = new HashSet<Integer>(set);
            return (OMOSetView)cloned;
        }
    }

Comment: set.toArray() не проходит, результат будет типа object
тогда прижутся сделать цикл...

Comment: помогите сделать union то аррай таким образом,пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Представьте, что случится, если мы запустим простой тест, где будет фигурировать хотя бы тройная вложенность union[union(set,set),union(set,set)] и сеты в 1000 элементов.

В Union и Set можно реализовать такой интерфейс

```
interface IndexableInt
{
    int get(int index);
    int size();
}
```

Тогда можно было бы индексировать в циклах без такого адового оверхеда и сохранить ваш код. Издержки будут увеличиваться линейно к уровню вложенности, а не геометрически.

Пример реализации:

```
class OMOSet implements OMOSetView, IndexableInt
{
    ArrayList<Integer> set = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...

    @Override
    public int get(int index)
    {
        return set.get(i);
    }
    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return set.size();
    }
}
class OMOSetUnion implements OMOSetView, IndexableInt
{
    OMOSetView setA;
    OMOSetView setB;
    // ...

    @Override
    public int get(int index)
    {
        int sizeOfFirstSet = setA.size();

        if (index < sizeOfFirstSet)
            return setA.get(index);
        else
            setA.get(index - sizeOfFirstSet); // множества идут один за другим
    }
    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return setA.size() + setB.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо,я вас поняла,но тут одна проблема. я не могу создавать геттры и сеттры,а только те методы,которые написаны

Comment: а делать set public - это вообще не хорошо

Comment: @evgeniya
Сеттер делать вообще не обязательно, а геттер здесь возвращает тип-значение, потому он отлично изолирован от внешнего мира.

Член set везде все также закрыт, как было у вас изначально. Только операции будут эффективнее, если не придется создавать промежуточный массив.

Comment: @evgeniya

(Пишу сюда, т.к. там лимит.)
Мне кажется, что вы здесь немного ошибаетесь с toArray(). HashSet наследует этот метод в том числе от AbstractCollection, который типизируется Integer в нашем случае. Потому метод возвратит что нужно.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toArray(T[])

Но, даже если не выйдет, вы можете кастовать =)

    @Override
    public int[] toArray() { return (int[])set.toArray(); }

Comment: @evgeniya

 Для Union. Это, наверное, не самое оптимальное решение, но пусть будет так:

    @Override
    public int[] toArray()
    {
        int [] arrA = setA.toArray();
        int lenA = arrA.length;

        int [] arrB = setB.toArray();
        int lenB = arrB.length;
        
        int[] newArray =  new int[ lenA + lenB ];

        int pos = 0;
        for (pos=0; pos < lenA; ++pos)
        {
            newArray[pos] = arrA[pos];
        }
        for (int i=0; i < lenB; ++pos, ++i)
        {
            newArray[pos] = arrB[i];
        }
        return newArray;
    }

Comment: @evgeniya
Хотя, можно и так)

    @Override
    public int[] toArray()
    {
        return  Arrays.asList( setA.toArray() ).addAll(setB).toArray();
    }

Comment: спасибо большое. я вот тоже все переписала. не могли бы вы посмотреть?вот например OMOSetUnion. http://pastebin.com/U4xcfC3v
По вашему мнению,тест бы прошел? я имею ввиду временной тест в той системе